# Find item in SharePoint list on a HyperLink field

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've looked at as many examples as possible and tried different combinations to what looks like a simple problem - I want to check if an O365 modern list item exists based on a URL (Hyperlink) field. My CAML is as below but returns no results - the list item URL field is a full url and the url variable is a text field containing the full URL also. I've also tried Eq and Contains.

```
"<View>
<Query>
<Where>
<BeginsWith>
<FieldRef Name='URL'/><Value Type='URL'>" + url + "
</Value>
</BeginsWith>
</Where>
</Query>
</View>"
```

Thanks,

John.

Full code

```
var OnePlaceURL = TenantBaseURL + "/sites/" + "oneplacesolutions";
            var clientSiteRelativePath = "/sites/" + alias; //Even though the list has the full URL the CAML query has to give a relative path - oddity of SP URL field
            var registerList = "DMS Clients";
                
            try
            {
                using (var context = new ClientContext(OnePlaceURL))
                {
                    context.Credentials = SPOCredentials;
                    Web web = context.Web;
                    context.Load(context.Web, w => w.Url);
                    context.ExecuteQueryRetry();


                    AddLogMessage(MessageLevel.Info, "AddSiteToOnePlaceSolutionsCentralRegister - loaded web" + context.Web.Url);

                    var targetList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(registerList);
                    context.Load(targetList);
                    context.Load(targetList.Fields);
                    context.Load(targetList.GetItemById(1));
                    context.ExecuteQueryRetry();

                    AddLogMessage(MessageLevel.Info, "AddSiteToOnePlaceSolutionsCentralRegister - loaded list and fields, itemCount:" + targetList.ItemCount);
                    

                    CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
                    query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='URL'/><Value Type='URL'>" + url + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
                    AddLogMessage(MessageLevel.Info, "ViewXML:" + query.ViewXml);

                    var itemList = targetList.GetItems(query);
                    context.Load(itemList); // loading all the fields   

                    context.ExecuteQueryRetry();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I test,if we add external web site url in list,we could use caml like this:

```
<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='link' /><Value Type='URL'>http://www.google.com</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>
```

If we add some internal site url in list,we need to create the caml like this:

```
<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='link' /><Value Type='URL'>/sites/dev/subsite</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>
```

We do not need to add our tenant url.

More reference:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2dc874ed-3a3d-4f26-b932-afb25c0142c8/caml-query-on-url-field?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

**Updated:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ValidateForm,"sp.js");

function ValidateForm(){

   
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("test3");
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(
        "<View><Query> <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='link' /><Value Type='Url'>/sites/dev/subsite</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
    var items = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(items);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,onSuccess),Function.createDelegate(this, onFail));
    function onSuccess(){
        
        var ListEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
        while (ListEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var currentItem = ListEnumerator.get_current();
        var link= currentItem.get_item("link");
        console.log(link);
     }
        
    }
    function onFail(sender,args){
    console.log(args.get_message());
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Amos - just to make sure I understand, currently the list item (Field:URL Type: Hyperlink) contains the value

'https://myTenant.sharepoint.com/sites/MySiteCollection'

and my URL variable in the CAML query is the same value (full URL) but if I understand correctly I need to parse my variable to be this instead:

/sites/MySiteCollection

as SharePoint is recognising that the full URL is a location on the tenant?

Thanks again,

John.

Comment: f the response is helpful, please mark it as answer and upvote it.Thank you.

Comment: Hi Amos, I've just tried it but when the variable is a relative path I get the error  `[Error] Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUrlValue' to type 'System.String'.` Do I need to change the CAML value type?

Comment: My full test code for your reference.Check the update.

Comment: My CAML looks very similiar <View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='URL'/><Value Type='URL'>/sites/[SiteCollectionName]</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View> but still getting the cast issue - would it be expecting a subsite maybe?

Comment: It' strange.No matter subsite,or site collections in tenant works well in my environment.Is the error reported when operating the hyperlink value?Could you share your full code?

Comment: Hi Amos sorry for the delay - full code added above. Basically I am check to see if a site is in a registry list already and if not then I add it as a new list item thanks. The url variable is the full URL of the site. I have also tried replaying url with the other variable clientSiteRelativePath shown also which is a relative path that throws the cast exception mentioned above